# default surefire not executing the test with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, maven-surefire-plugin

I am working on a quite simple Spring Boot 2.4.2 project, using the BOM :

```
  <dependency>
    <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

when running `mvn clean verify`, I get this : we see that no test is found by Surefire 2.12.4

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ api-testing --- 
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\vincent\IdeaProjects\api-testing\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------  T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

I don't understand why.. I tried several things, and even if it's not recommended, I tried overriding the version by adding this in my pom :

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.2</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

And now my test is found !

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ api-testing ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running de.vincent.AssetReferentialServiceTest
```

I am really surprised by this Spring Boot behavior - I assume I am missing something.. but what ?

Note : my test is a Junit 5 test, and I have no Junit 4 related jars in my classpath - only Junit Jupiter 5.7.0 and Junit platform 1.7.0

Thanks

Comment: Why is it even using that version of the plugin? Spring Boot already uses a newer version for compatibility with JUnit5. So either you are using an old version of maven which uses and old version of that plugin or you are already overriding it somewhere. Ah the main issue is that you are importing the bom and not using Spring Boot as a parent (thus it won't set the version for the plugin and it will use the default version as specified with maven in the super pom).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot @M. Deinum for pointing out the issue in the comment.

Of course, using Spring Boot parent pom helps a lot in using the proper plugins versions !

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
</parent>
```

The BOM will only help for the dependencies, not the build plugins.